# InfluxDB refusing connections

Tags: linux, docker, shell, influxdb

I am working with influxDB. My requirement is that i have to edit **init-influxdb.sh** file and add a small script at the end of this file. My **init-influxdb.sh** file code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

AUTH_ENABLED="$INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED"

INIT_USERS=$([ ! -z "$AUTH_ENABLED" ] && [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER" ] && echo 1 || echo)

if [ -z "$INFLUXDB_META_DIR" ]; then
    META_DIR="/var/lib/influxdb/meta"
else
    META_DIR="$INFLUXDB_META_DIR"
fi

if ( [ ! -z "$INIT_USERS" ] || [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ] || [ "$(ls -A /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 2> /dev/null)" ] ) && [ ! "$(ls -d "$META_DIR" 2>/dev/null)" ]; then

    INIT_QUERY=""
    CREATE_DB_QUERY="CREATE DATABASE $INFLUXDB_DB"

    if [ ! -z "$INIT_USERS" ]; then

        if [ -z "$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD" ]; then
            INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD="$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c32;echo;)"
            echo "INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD:$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD"
        fi

        INIT_QUERY="CREATE USER \"$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER\" WITH PASSWORD '$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"
    elif [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ]; then
        INIT_QUERY="$CREATE_DB_QUERY"
    else
        INIT_QUERY="SHOW DATABASES"
    fi

    INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT="8086"

    INFLUXDB_HTTP_BIND_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:$INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT INFLUXDB_HTTP_HTTPS_ENABLED=false influxd "$@" &
pid="$!"

    INFLUX_CMD="influx -host 127.0.0.1 -port $INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT -execute "

    for i in {30..0}; do
        if $INFLUX_CMD "$INIT_QUERY" &> /dev/null; then
            break
        fi
        echo 'influxdb init process in progress...'
        sleep 1
    done

    if [ "$i" = 0 ]; then
        echo >&2 'influxdb init process failed.'
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -z "$INIT_USERS" ]; then

        INFLUX_CMD="influx -host 127.0.0.1 -port $INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT -username ${INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER} -password ${INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD} -execute "

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ]; then
            $INFLUX_CMD "$CREATE_DB_QUERY"
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_USER" ] && [ -z "$INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD" ]; then
            INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD="$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c32;echo;)"
            echo "INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD:$INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD"
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_USER" ]; then
            $INFLUX_CMD "CREATE USER \"$INFLUXDB_USER\" WITH PASSWORD '$INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD'"

            $INFLUX_CMD "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM \"$INFLUXDB_USER\""

            if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ]; then
                $INFLUX_CMD "GRANT ALL ON \"$INFLUXDB_DB\" TO \"$INFLUXDB_USER\""
            fi
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER" ] && [ -z "$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER_PASSWORD" ]; then
            INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER_PASSWORD="$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c32;echo;)"
            echo "INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER_PASSWORD:$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER_PASSWORD"
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER" ]; then
            $INFLUX_CMD "CREATE USER \"$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER\" WITH PASSWORD '$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER_PASSWORD'"
            $INFLUX_CMD "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM \"$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER\""

            if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ]; then
                $INFLUX_CMD "GRANT WRITE ON \"$INFLUXDB_DB\" TO \"$INFLUXDB_WRITE_USER\""
            fi
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_READ_USER" ] && [ -z "$INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD" ]; then
            INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD="$(< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c32;echo;)"
            echo "INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD:$INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD"
        fi

        if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_READ_USER" ]; then
            $INFLUX_CMD "CREATE USER \"$INFLUXDB_READ_USER\" WITH PASSWORD '$INFLUXDB_READ_USER_PASSWORD'"
            $INFLUX_CMD "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM \"$INFLUXDB_READ_USER\""

            if [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ]; then
                $INFLUX_CMD "GRANT READ ON \"$INFLUXDB_DB\" TO \"$INFLUXDB_READ_USER\""
            fi
        fi

    fi

    for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
            *.iql)    echo "$0: running $f"; $INFLUX_CMD "$(cat ""$f"")"; echo ;;
            *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
        esac
        echo
    done

    if ! kill -s TERM "$pid" || ! wait "$pid"; then
        echo >&2 'influxdb init process failed. (Could not stop influxdb)'
        exit 1
    fi

fi
# My custom script starts here
INIT_QUERY="CREATE USER \"$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER\" WITH PASSWORD '$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"

INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT="8086"

INFLUX_CMD="influx -host 127.0.0.1 -port $INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT -username admin -password admin -execute "

echo 'Creating admin user of influx db'
$INFLUX_CMD "$INIT_QUERY"
echo 'Admin user of influx db created successfully'

echo 'Enabling authentication on influxdb server'
if [ -z "$AUTH_ENABLED" ]; then
    AUTH_ENABLED="$(grep -iE '^\s*auth-enabled\s*=\s*true' /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf | grep -io 'true' | cat)"
else
    AUTH_ENABLED="$(echo "$INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED" | grep -io 'true' | cat)"
fi
```

Issue is that, after printing "**Creating admin user of influx db**" i get the error "**Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086: Get http://localhost:8086/ping: dial tcp [::1]:8086: getsockopt
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.**"

What can be the possible issue here ? There isn't any error on any other query. Why i am getting this error. I am stuck, any help would be much appreciated.

My **DockerFile** is:

```
FROM influxdb:1.7.6


ENV INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER="admin"
ENV INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin"
ENV INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED=true
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod 777 /init-influxdb.sh

COPY init-influxdb.sh /

RUN chmod 777 /init-influxdb.sh

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: where do you use this script?

Comment: This file "init-influxdb.sh" runs automatically when the container starts (runs) @Stefano

Comment: I read both changes before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the DB is not yet started when you try to run the statement.

Checking the rest of the script you can see their solution to the problem:

```sh
    for i in {30..0}; do
        if $INFLUX_CMD "$INIT_QUERY" &> /dev/null; then
            break
        fi
        echo 'influxdb init process in progress...'
        sleep 1
    done

    if [ "$i" = 0 ]; then
        echo >&2 'influxdb init process failed.'
        exit 1
    fi
```

I think your setup does not involve the execution of that portion of the script though.

Comment: Well, thats not the solution. If the "ADMIN" user already exists then the above loop will never break. The loop will only break if the "ADMIN" user does not already exists @Stefano. BTW that is the default code of the script which you posted.

Comment: well, clearly the DB is not answering when the script gets there. Otherwise why repeating this loop 30 times with a `sleep 1` in the middle?

Comment: The code which you posted is in a if condition i.e.  "if ( [ ! -z "$INIT_USERS" ] || [ ! -z "$INFLUXDB_DB" ] || [ "$(ls -A /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 2> /dev/null)" ] ) && [ ! "$(ls -d "$META_DIR" 2>/dev/null)" ]; then . . . If database already exists then script will never go into the if block and will directly comes to my custom script. If i put your posted code in my custom script and ADMIN user already exists, it never breaks the loop @Stefano
"

Comment: what are you talking about? the `break` is there exactly for that reason. Anyway my point was that your portion of the script is not dealing with the possibility that the DB is not ready to listen to any command.

Comment: code will break when the if condition will become true and the if condition is not becoming true @Stefano

Comment: I'm simply pointing out that the solution they use is to repeat the same command 30 times and to have a `sleep 1` in the middle.